# Im new to coding and was trying to loop through a list and kept coming up with the error code list index out of range. Why does this not work?

Tags: python, list

```
def number_practice(nums):
    count = 0
    for i in nums:
        if nums[i] != 20:
            count += nums[i]
        else:
            return count

    return count
```

I understand I could use for i in range(len(nuts)):
but I just wanted to know why this doesnt work.
The code below is similar and returns the list back starting at the second number.

```
for i in lista:
    print(lista[i])
```

If anyone could explain why this happens with this loop I would appreciate it thank you!

Comment: You used the list element as an index back into the list.  This is almost always a conceptual mistake.  For instance, if your list is `[17, 100, 50]`, then you are trying to print the values in *positions* 17, 100, 50 -- all three of which are out of range.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing right now is looping through every element in lista, then printing out `lista[element of lista]`.  This won't work because you already have the element of `lista`, you just need to print `i`.  So like this:

```py
for i in lista:
    print(i)
```

and

```py
def number_practice(nums): # Your indentation here was wrong in the original question
    count = 0
    for i in nums:
        if i != 20:
            count += i
        else:
            return count

    return count
```