# to find the sum of only the negative numbers of the list

Tags: python, list, indexing, sum

when i used for loop for length of the list I got the correct answer.But when I use for loop for I in range list: I got the correct wrong answer [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr1FZ.jpg)
the first Image shows when value of i is taken.the second image shoes when for loop is take for length of list.what's the problem here?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35KRy.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/error messages. Post the formatted text directly here on SO. You can edit your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70995740/edit).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Im new to coding and was trying to loop through a list and kept coming up with the error code list index out of range. Why does this not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68091282/im-new-to-coding-and-was-trying-to-loop-through-a-list-and-kept-coming-up-with-t)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)(to filter negative numbers) and then `sum` them -

```
>>> p = [1,2,-3,4,-4,5,6]
>>> sum(filter(lambda x: x < 0, p))
-7
```

Answer (score 2):

you are indexing the list like this p[1],p[2],p[-3]...

instead you should iterate through the values

```
p = [1,2,-3,4,-4,5,6]
t = 0
for i in p:
    if i < 0:
        t += i
print(t)
```

or use range(len(p)):

```
p = [1,2,-3,4,-4,5,6]
t = 0
for i in range(len(p)):
    if p[i] < 0:
        t += p[i]
print(t)
```

or use enumerate to access the index (optimal way):

```
p = [1,2,-3,4,-4,5,6]
t = 0
for i, value in enumerate(p):
    if p[i] < 0:
        t += p[i]
print(t)
```

Comment: Using `range` and an index access is an anti-pattern in Python. Never use this if you want to loop over every entry in a list. It's more to write, harder to read and it's running slower. If you need the index and the value then use `enumerate`.

Comment: true. edited it

Comment: @npho111 Your explanation of the way to use `range` is fine, since that was the error in the original code. I just wanted to make clear that this is not the optimal way to loop over a list.

Answer (score 0):

This is the python code you had in the posted picture.

```
p = [1,2,-3,4,-4,5,6]
t = 0
for i in p:
   if p[i] < 0:
     t+=p[i]
print(t)
```

when you use `for i in p` , we iterate through the list unlike accessing the list values by their index
If you print each of the value during the loop

```
for i in p:
     print(i)
output: 
1
2
-3
4
-4
5
6
```

Also note that `p[-3]` indicates 3rd element from tail of the list
so the values `p[i]` in your code are `p[1],[2],p[-3],p[4],p[-4],p[5],p[6]`
equivalent to `2,-3,-4,-4,5,6` giving you a result of `((-3)+(-4)+(-4)) = -11`